# How do I authenticate with the Tikkie API?

Tags: authentication, payment, banking, payment-request-api, open-banking

How do I authenticate with the Tikkie API? I want to use the Tikkie API but I not sure how to get started with the authentication.

Comment: Hey all, just to make sure this is question that was asked alot so to catalog it I asked and answered the question here. Good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.  Create key pair & share it

You will need this to authenticate, you can create it by executing these commands in for example bash or powershell (if you have openssl installed).

```
// generates RSA private key of 2048 bit size
openssl genrsa -out private_rsa.pem 2048

// generates public key from the private key
openssl rsa -in private_rsa.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public_rsa.pem
```

Once you have created the key pair, share the public key with ABN AMRO. Send it via email to api.support@nl.abnamro.com with the name of your app and your email.

---

## 2. Check your options

Before you start coding do quick check on existing tools which can help you, you don't have to reinvent the wheel now do you? ;)

#### Option 1 - SDKs

You can grab a SDK for your language and start coding right away.

- [php-tikkie](https://github.com/jarnovanleeuwen/php-tikkie) in PHP by Jarno van Leeuwen
- [tikkie-api](https://github.com/KentaaNL/tikkie-api) in Ruby by KentaaNL
- [node-tikkie](https://github.com/DanielHuisman/node-tikkie) in Node.js by Daniel Huisman
- [tikkie-api-dotnet](https://github.com/chusjp/tikkie-api-dotnet) in .NET by chusjp

#### Option 2 - Code it yourself!

When you are stubborn or your language is not supported, you can code the authentication logic and maybe more yourself. Check the links below for some information about how to get started.

- [ABN AMRO Developer Portal](https://developer.abnamro.com/get-started#authentication): here you can find more detailed information about authenticating with the API.
- [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/): the offical JWT site where you can check your JWT, find libaries to  help you and information about the JWT.

---

## 3. Ready, set and go!?

Sure, why not? If you have any question or feedback please do post it or reach out to ABN AMRO at api.support@nl.abnamro.com